# I can't understand this Horner's rule implementation in extended fields GF(p^n)

Tags: c, algorithm, math, gmp

I'm trying to understand the implementation of the Shamir's Secret Sharing Scheme from [this (old) implementation on github](https://github.com/aseidlitz/ssss-win32/blob/master/src/ssss_rk/ssss.c), and I'm struggling with Horner's rule in extended fields GF(p^n):

```
void horner(int n, mpz_t y, const mpz_t x, const mpz_t coeff[])
{
  int i;
  mpz_set(y, x);
  for(i = n - 1; i; i--) {
    field_add(y, y, coeff[i]);
    field_mult(y, y, x);
  }
  field_add(y, y, coeff[0]);
}
```

Why does `add` come first and only then `mult`? What's the algorithm? Why not something like:

```
  mpz_set(y,coeff[n-1]);
  for(i = n - 2; i!=-1; i--) {
    field_mult(y, y, x);
    field_add(y,y,coeff[i]);
  }
```

Comment: The second variant lacks the x^n term.

Comment: Main question: why use [Monic polynomial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monic_polynomial) in the [Horner's rule](https://www.math10.com/en/algebra/horner.html) in this case ([Shamir's Secret Sharing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shamir%27s_Secret_Sharing))?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Translating this `horner` function with normal addition and multiplication symbols, we get:

```
y = x;                     // mpz_set(y, x);
for(i = n - 1; i; i--) {
    y = y + coeff[i];      // field_add(y, y, coeff[i]);
    y = y * x              // field_mult(y, y, x);
}
y = y + coeff[0]           // field_add(y, y, coeff[0]);
```

Hence this computes the following:
[image: Horner's algorithm computation of degree n monic polynomial with coefficients (cn-1, .., c0)]

You can see it does not compute any polynomial, but it is a variant of Horner's algorithm to compute a [monic polynomial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monic_polynomial).

Now what you propose:

```
y = coeff[n-1];               // mpz_set(y,coeff[n-1]);
for(i = n - 2; i!=-1; i--) {
    y = y * x;                // field_mult(y, y, x);
    y = y + coeff[i];         // field_add(y,y,coeff[i]);
}
```

Thus you compute the following:
[image: Horner's algorithm to compute degree n-1 polynomial with coefficients (cn-1, .., 0)]
You can see the highest-order term is missing.

If you want to have all the operations inside the body of the loop, you can.
After all, it's only two ways of decomposing a series of alternating instructions differently:

```
operation    value of y                                    loop iteration
                                                 add-mult loop      mult-add loop
                x                               initialization         n-1
add       x + coeff[n-1]                             n-1               n-1
mult     (x + coeff[n-1]) * x                        n-1               n-2
add      (x + coeff[n-1]) * x + coeff[n-2]           n-2               n-2
mult    ((x + coeff[n-1]) * x + coeff[n-2]) * x      n-2               n-3
          ...etc...
```

But you need to explicitly initialize `y` to the value `1` (which is the implicit `coeff[n]`) so that you can start by multiplying by `x` and get the correct highest-order term.

```
y = 1;                        // mpz_set(y,1);
for(i = n - 1; i!=-1; i--) {  // NOTICE n - 1 NOT n - 2
    y = y * x;                // field_mult(y, y, x);
    y = y + coeff[i];         // field_add(y,y,coeff[i]);
}
```

You can count that you now perform one more multiplication, and it is multiplying `1 * x`. On a finite field this is typically done with log and antilog tables, so you might as well avoid such a useless multiplication, especially if you're going to evaluate polynomials a lot.

**TL;DR: This way of writing Horner's algorithm puts the last addition and the first multiplication outside of the loop's body. Because the highest-order coefficient is `1` this multiplication is then completely removed.**

To clarify: the highest-order term is kept, but is then `x^n` instead of being `1 * x^n`. You spare one multiplication for the exact same result.

Comment: "Because the highest-order coefficient is 1 this multiplication is then completely removed."
Why then in the formula above we need 'x^n', if it removed? And as with coefficient 1 it is removed? Is something I can not understand ...
n=3: y=((1x+C[2])x+C[1])x+C[0]=x^3+C[2]x^2+C[1]x+C[0]. What is happening with 'x^3'?
Thanks.

Comment: yes, understood: mpz_set_ui(y,1) instead mpz_set(y,x) 
I meant: [polynomial is expressed](https://www.math10.com/en/algebra/horner.html) as:
f(x) = a0 + a1x + a2x2 + ... + akxk = sum a[k]x^k. Whence appeared x^n?
n=3: y=((x+C[2])x+C[1])x+C[0]=**x^3**+C[2]x^2+C[1]x+C[0].
x=2: **8**+4C[2]+2C[1]+C[0]  not the same 4C[2]+2C[1]+C[0].

Comment: Your expression works in the general case. In this specific implementation, you are looking at a function that returns a polynomial where a[n] = 1, always.

Comment: Sorry, I still can not understand why In this implementation x^n without coefficient c[n], i.e. x^n + sum c[i]x^i, 0..n-1 instead of sum c[i]x^i 0..n.

Comment: There is no why if you look at the function, it is what the function does. Why was it written that way? Because the programmer needed [Monic Polynomials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monic_polynomial). Why does he need that? Well, you'll have to ask him or look at the rest of the algorithm. But now, you know what the function does exactly.